# How to post to friend's notification area?

Tags: c#, facebook, notifications, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a web site facebook app. I can login and post to users wall.What I really want is when a user creates an image on my web site , he can create a notification on couple friends to take an action on the image. How can I do this ? 
I have this code but I don't see a notification at my notification area ?

```
 var f = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = f.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            client_secret = FACEBOOK_SECRET,
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        });

        var token = result.access_token as string;

        var reqClient = new FacebookClient(token);
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["message"] = "Invitation to action message";
        args["data"] = "Invitation to action data";

        var reqResult = reqClient.Post("/" + facebookId.ToString() + "/apprequests", args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app generated request go to the bookmarks counter and not to the top notifications (with the globe image).

There's no way for an app to send that kind of notification to a user (that I'm aware of).
You can check in the [Social Channels guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) on the options that are available for you, also you can check the [Requests documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/).

Comment: When you're in facebook, on the left menu you see the *Apps*, in that menu you get all of your bookmarked apps, and for each you can have a "balloon" with a number in it, which is the counter of notifications you have for that app.

Comment: OK now I can see it, I add canvas app and Users can send requests which appear in notification area.

Comment: User requests will appear in the notification "globe", while app requests will show as a counter in the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [app notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/). The guide I've linked to shows a lot of documentation.